# Isnt Raspberry PI Fully open source hardware yet?

Tags: hardware

Almost ALL mobile processors are ARM, but sure a design can be made with an ARM Processor which is open source. This question is different from the question asked on [How is Raspberry Pi "open source" if it uses ARM?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/how-is-raspberry-pi-open-source-if-it-uses-arm).

Both BBB and Raspberry PI use ARM chips, but I would like to know the differences in open-source-ness of these two designs.

This link directs to a page which states that the Raspberry PI is not fully open source hardware. I do not understand this statement. I believe the schematics are available and the IC numbers are available. What more needs to be opened up?

The statement is as follows:

> What will matter the most to many people is the fact that the Pi is
>   still closed source hardware with limited documentation of the design
>   and no ability to customize or manage the supply chain. This is only
>   part of why many people consider the Bone more suited to higher
>   educational and professional use. Quality manufacturing in the US is
>   also frequently seen as a bonus by a developer community with many
>   professional Linux consultants looking to help create real products.
>   Open hardware derivatives like the Ninja Spheramid and BBP (BeagleBone
>   3D Printer) are just the start of new Bone-related designs popping up
>   this year. This is possible due to the open hardware nature of the
>   Bones and use of the Sitara devices that are available for nearly
>   anyone to buy.

Comment: See piman's answer on the dupe.  The pi will never have completely open source hardware unless they ditch the Broadcom SoC, which is the core of the whole thing.

Comment: It's a sterile argument.  The Broadcom chip and the binary blobs needed to boot are the primary complaint.  A lot of it comes across as sour grapes from competing platforms.

Comment: This is NOT a dublicate question. These binary blobs are not there in the beagle bone black? I am asking in comparison with the beaglebone, is there still a chance the beaglebone be not fully open source too?

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum, so open ended questions which lead to further questions ("is there still a chance the beaglebone be not fully open source too") don't work.  It's a duplicate in the sense they both boil down to, "In what way is the pi hardware *not* open source?".  Questions about the beagle bone are obviously better somewhere else, but, to clarify a bit, the kernel itself is one big "binary blob", and in that sense, all systems do need one to boot.  "Open source" refers to the *source code* from which a binary is compiled.  Some of the pi firmware is not open source.

Comment: Here's [Broadcom's position](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/LICENCE.broadcom). Note "redistribution and use **in binary form, without modification**" -- no source code, no modifications == not open source.

Comment: So as per my understanding, it is yet possibe to compile a kernel to the raspberry PI but there are some files (blobs) we know what they do but we do not have an idea about their code. Am I right?

Comment: A new interview with Eben http://www.raspberrypi.org/the-raspberry-pi-guy-interviews-eben-and-gordon/ where he state this year they will be move than ever trying to get away from the binary blobs.

Comment: Obviously the kernel is open source (the GPLv2  at work , folks !) , and in an unprecedented incident Broadcom even released something bearing resemblance to a datasheet for the BCM2835 **to the general public** ! This all bears Mr. Uptons handwriting ...

Comment: For hysterical reasons the Pi boots the GPU first , and the GPU firmware is closed-source. The GPU then starts the ARM , ergo without a libre GPU bootloader an libre ARM bootloader doesn't make sense for most Free Software Enthusiasts