# Is it possible to build a Raspberry Pi yourself?

Tags: hardware, setup, driver

As covered in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27005/how-is-raspberry-pi-open-source-if-it-uses-arm), the Raspberry Pi isn't open source. However, if one were to manually buy all the components on the board and solder them in an identical manner, what further steps would be required to turn it into an actually functioning board?

Answer (score 6):

If your idea is to make an exact carbon copy of the Pi 2, you won't succeed.
While @joan stated that the OTP contents are not shared to the public, the actual SoC is also not available.  The BCM2836 is a custom design for the Raspberry Pi Foundation and I doubt it is available through the common channels.

That being said there is a wide variety of Raspberry-like-a-likes on the market.  There's of course the [Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc) (which is also being [cloned](http://makezine.com/2012/04/24/soapbox-my-top-10-favorite-arduino-compatible-clones-and-derivatives/) or even [counterfeited](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Products/Counterfeit)) and the [Beagleboard](http://beagleboard.org).  Then there are is the [Odroid](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G140610189490&tab_idx=1), the [Banana](http://www.bananapi.org), the [Pandaboard](http://pandaboard.org), the [pcDuino](http://www.linksprite.com/?page_id=782), the [Intel Galileo](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/embedded/products/galileo/galileo-overview.html) and at least ten more.

Obviously copying the Raspberry Pi will result in a lawsuit.  But if your goal is to create a custom platform for your specific application, [partnering up with an OEM](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/can-i-use-raspberry-pi-in-commercial-production/34063#34063) might be a solution.  And if you need a vast amount of boards (1,000+) I'm sure some of the above cloners are up for helping you with that.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest obstacle I can think of is programming the OTP (One-time programmable) memory of the Broadcom SoC so that it will boot.

I am not sure what infomation is publically available for that purpose.